# Get file like object from contents of GoogleDriveFile pydrive

Tags: python, pydrive

Here are the docs:

```
FetchContent(*args, **kwargs)
```

Download file’s content from `download_url.`

Raises:

```
ApiRequestError, FileNotUploadedError, FileNotDownloadableError
```

I tried supplying `GoogleDriveFile.metadata['selfLInk']`
and it didn't work.... there also a `GoogleDriveFile.get method`
which has 1 argument (i got from errors) I have no idea what that argument is or what it does.. Also `GoogleDriveFile.content` is none

Just trying to do this:

```
data=GoogleDriveFile.getcontent()
z=data.read(1024)
while z:
     newdata=do stuff(z)
     localfile.write(newdata)
     z=data.read(1024)
z.close()
localfile.close()
```

I think pydrive uses the v2 api, I tried doing something liek this:
https://youtu.be/-7YH6rdR-tk?t=573
How do I implement that with pydrive? you can see the data part where he writes data to local file.

```
drive=login()#

z=drive
an='file.ext' #set permission to anyoen with link cna download
zz = z.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for f in zz:
    if f['title']==an:
        ww=f.metadata['downloadUrl']
        print ww
        print dir(f.FetchContent(ww))
        break
import sys
sys.exit()

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: that's GetContentFile  which saves to a local file, doesnt return a file like object, the pure API does have a method for this, I saw it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7YH6rdR-tk  Trying to figure hwo to call it from pydrive

Comment: GetContent also returns NONE. i'm wondering if i have to set permissions to be able to get that content...

Comment: Permission set to anyone can download that has link, passed downloadLink to f.FetchContent(arg)  still showsup as None

Answer (score 2):

You call FetchContent()
then the bytesIO object is
.content